# ANTLR: VERY slow parsing

Tags: antlr4, operator-precedence

I have successfully split my expressions into arithmetic and boolean expressions like this:

```
/* entry point */
parse: formula EOF;


formula : (expr|boolExpr);

/* boolean expressions : take math expr and use boolean operators on them */

boolExpr
  : bool                                            
  | l=expr operator=(GT|LT|GEQ|LEQ) r=expr          
  | l=boolExpr operator=(OR|AND) r=boolExpr         
  | l=expr (not='!')? EQUALS r=expr                 
  | l=expr BETWEEN low=expr AND high=expr           
  | l=expr IS (NOT)? NULL                           
  | l=atom LIKE regexp=string                       
  | l=atom ('IN'|'in') '(' string (',' string)* ')' 
  | '(' boolExpr ')'                                
  ;

/* arithmetic expressions */
expr
    : atom                                                 
    | (PLUS|MINUS) expr                                    
    | l=expr operator=(MULT|DIV) r=expr                    
    | l=expr operator=(PLUS|MINUS) r=expr                  
    | function=IDENTIFIER '(' (expr ( ','  expr )* ) ? ')' 
    | '(' expr ')'                                         
    ;

atom
    : number
    | variable
    | string
    ;
```

But now I have HUGE performance problems. Some formulas I try to parse are utterly slow, to the point that it has become unbearable: more than an hour (I stopped at that point) to parse this:

```
-4.77+[V1]*-0.0071+[V1]*[V1]*0+[V2]*-0.0194+[V2]*[V2]*0+[V3]*-0.00447932+[V3]*[V3]*-0.0017+[V4]*-0.00003298+[V4]*[V4]*0.0017+[V5]*-0.0035+[V5]*[V5]*0+[V6]*-4.19793004+[V6]*[V6]*1.5962+[V7]*12.51966636+[V7]*[V7]*-5.7058+[V8]*-19.06596752+[V8]*[V8]*28.6281+[V9]*9.47136506+[V9]*[V9]*-33.0993+[V10]*0.001+[V10]*[V10]*0+[V11]*-0.15397774+[V11]*[V11]*-0.0021+[V12]*-0.027+[V12]*[V12]*0+[V13]*-2.02963068+[V13]*[V13]*0.1683+[V14]*24.6268688+[V14]*[V14]*-5.1685+[V15]*-6.17590512+[V15]*[V15]*1.2936+[V16]*2.03846688+[V16]*[V16]*-0.1427+[V17]*9.02302288+[V17]*[V17]*-1.8223+[V18]*1.7471106+[V18]*[V18]*-0.1255+[V19]*-30.00770912+[V19]*[V19]*6.7738
```

Do you have any idea on what the problem is?

The parsing stops when the parser enters the `formula` grammar rule.

**edit** Original problem here:

My grammar allows this:

```
// ( 1 LESS_EQUALS 2 )
1 <= 2
```

But the way I expressed it in my G4 file makes it also accept this:

```
// ( ( 1 LESS_EQUALS 2 ) LESS_EQUALS 3 )
1 <= 2 <= 3
```

Which I don't want.

My grammar contains this:

```
expr
    : atom                                                 # atomArithmeticExpr
    | (PLUS|MINUS) expr                                    # plusMinusExpr
    | l=expr operator=('*'|'/') r=expr                     # multdivArithmeticExpr
    | l=expr operator=('+'|'-') r=expr                     # addsubtArithmeticExpr
    | l=expr operator=('>'|'<'|'>='|'<=') r=expr           # comparisonExpr
[...]
```

How can I tell Antlr that this is not acceptable?

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix the speed problem? I'm running into it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just split root into two. Either rename root 'expr' into 'rootexpr', or vice versa.

```
rootExpr
    : atom                                                 # atomArithmeticExpr
    | (PLUS|MINUS) expr                                    # plusMinusExpr
    | l=expr operator=('*'|'/') r=expr                     # multdivArithmeticExpr
    | l=expr operator=('+'|'-') r=expr                     # addsubtArithmeticExpr
    | l=expr operator=('>'|'<'|'>='|'<=') r=expr           # comparisonExpr
```

EDIT: You cannot have cyclic reference => expr node in expr rule.

Comment: Uh? But then what defines an `expr` ?

Comment: The question you had was, how to tell the Antlr, it is not acceptable. So I am telling you not to use cyclic reference if you do want to allow only one operator expression. Of course it is not entire grammar, just the point. expr rule can be defined as distinct rule or you can use 'atom' rule if applies.